# Using HTML5 FileReader, c#, and jquery to upload file

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to upload a file to a generic HttpHandler in c#.  I get the file using drag and drop events:

```
 $s("#dropArea")
    .on("drop", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();

        var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];

        var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        $s.ajax({
            url: MY_SERVER_URL,
            type: "POST",
            data: reader.result,
            headers: {
                "x-file-name": file.name
            }                
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

this seems to work fine, but when posted to the ashx page, I try decode the image like so:

```
var form = context.Request.Form[0];
var attachment = form.Split(new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];

byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(attachment);
```

When I try to write `byte[] data` to the disk, the resulting file is not correct.  Where am I going wrong?

**edit**:  I have also tried using FormData, but the Request.Form and Request.Files collections are always empty and I have to parse the boundaries manually.  This is the code I was using to do that:

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(file.name, file);

    $s.ajax({
        url: MY_SERVER_URL,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
        headers: {
            "x-file-name": file.name            
    });
```

Comment: And why wouldn't you do like normal people, and use a `formData` object to upload the image ?

Comment: @adeneo because the Request.Form collection is always empty when I do that.  I set the content type to "multipart/form-data" in jQuery and it just comes through Request.InputStream, which then requires me to parse out the boundaries.

Comment: In the second one, remove the headers and set the contentType to `false`, and see if it works.

Comment: @adeneo thank you, that was it.  Why does setting the contentType to false change it?  I didn't see in the jquery docs where that behavior is described.

Comment: Setting the contentType to false forces jQuery not to add a Content-Type header, and subsequnetly removing the boundary string, it has to be set to `false` to work with files.

Comment: If you want, add this as a comment @adeneo so I can accept it as a solution.

Comment: Sure, just a second!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending files with jQuery's `$.ajax` one has to set the `processData` and `contentType` options to `false`.

Setting the `processData` to false makes sure jQuery doesn't process the formData object in any way.

Setting the `contentType` to false makes sure jQuery doesn't add a boundary, something it would normally do. That is, jQuery adds the contentType, ***and*** a boundary, so it looks something like :

```
Content-Type=multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------993434535254
```

we don't want jQuery to set a certain boudary, as then the serverside wouldn't understand what's going on, so to avoid it the `contentType` **has** to be set to `false` when sending files.

```
var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append(file.name, file);

$s.ajax({
    url: MY_SERVER_URL,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
});
```

and that's really all the options that are needed to send files with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

What browser did you try this on? what version of jquery are you using for this? Include more specifics to increase your chance of finding the answer.

Since you are uploading images you may want to use a component that can resize/convert or whatever as well or your users might upload the wrong type, may want to consider a component that helps you with this.

File uploads on the web can be tricky, instead of trying to re-invent the wheel, save yourself some hair-pulling and pick a library like plupload that people have worked on for many years.

Even if you get this code above to work in your specific case and you think it works, it will very likely be buggy in every single scenario you have not tested. With web file uploads every little detail down to the headers sent with the file transfer have to be exactly right or it will not work. If any of your files are large depending on what webserver you are using you may need to tweak those settings, etc.

I don't know what is wrong with your code but I do know that to do this properly is a lot more complex than what you have above.